# The word "go" with different kinds of "sounds"

Tags: spoken-english

I heard the sentence from someone:

> When we prickle a balloon with a needle **it goes bang!**

Is the sentence **valid?**

Can I say:

> It goes **swish.**

as well?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We **prick** or **pop**  balloons rather than **prickling** them. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/prickle

Answer (score 1):

"Go" can be used in the sense of "say". Although technically a balloon cannot talk or say something, we can think of this as an extended sense.

This is very common. But as Garner (2015) note, it is non-standard at best

> The use of go as a synonym for say is seemingly part of every American teenager’s vocabulary (“So I go, ‘Whattaya mean?’ and he goes, ‘Whattaya mean by askin’ that?’ ”). It occurs in the past tense also: “Then he went, like, ‘No way!’” This is low-level slang. 
>   Garner (2015)

Comment: Wow this answer was downvoted 2 minutes after it was posted and I haven't even edited it yet. I wish the downvoter had explained why they downvoted it. I wanna know how the other answer explains it better.

Comment: It's very common in the UK too. [@user178049 Weird! The other answer's gone now. I didn't see it.]

Comment: We use it of animal noises too ('The cow goes _moo_' etc.).

Comment: I would rather think that the sense of "go" is make noise, and the meaning "say" is an extension from the meaning "make noise".